# Importing own Plugin via zip fails - classFactory error, no module named 'pysal.lib.weights'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

(To be precise, the installation itself works, but I can't load the plugin because of the mentioned class factory error.)

The plugin is made by me, etc. At first, it failed with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysal'`. I have already figured out I can fix that by running `python -m pip install pysal` in the OSGeo4W shell, and that indeed fixed this error.

Unfortunately, the error simply changed: Now it's **`No module named 'pysal.lib.weights'`**. (This import is attempted in the first place because one of my scripts explicitly calls this line.)

**So, the actual question:**
While my primary goal with this question is of course to find a fix to this problem with the pysal.lib.weights import, I am also hoping someone here might be able to explain *why* this is happening. My code linting can find the module just fine, so I don't understand why QGIS can't - I do *think* I have set my Interpreter to the one matching QGIS as well: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe. *Is* that the Python QGIS uses? If not, that might at least explain that particular difference.

**Versions:**
I'm attempting to install the plugin in QGIS LTR, so 3.28.0, though I have attempted it on 3.22.12 as well with the same results.